# Getting "#ReferenceError: connection is not defined"

Tags: discord.js

I've been using the code from [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#joining-voice-channels) and keep getting this error when I try to make it join
Here's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const PREFIX = '%';

const request = require('request');

const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var servers = {};

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('This client is online!');
})

client.on('message', message => {

let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0]) {
    case 'image':
        var imreq = (args[1])
        image(message, imreq);
        break;
    case 'bruh':
        client.on('message', async message => {
            // Join the same voice channel of the author of the message
            if (message.member.voice.channel) {
                const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
            }
        });
        const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\Users\jayja\Downloads\Bruh Sound Effect 2.mp3 ');

        dispatcher.on('start', () => {
            console.log('audio.mp3 is now playing!');
        });

        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('audio.mp3 has finished playing!');
        });

        // Always remember to handle errors appropriately!
        dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

        break;
}

});

 function image(message, imreq) {

var options = {
    url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + imreq,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "text/html",
        "User-Agent": "Chrome"
    }
};
request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

    var links = $(".image a.link");

    var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => 
    links.eq(i).attr("href"));

    console.log(urls);

    if (!urls.length) {

        return;
    }

    // Send result
    message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
  });

  }

  client.login(token)
```

Heres a screenshot of the terminal:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgrBz.png)

Comment: It would be interesting to see what comes before and after your code snippet. Pretty sur eit's not necessary to listen on the message event, because this will be triggered by a message command somehow right? Hard to say with this code snippet tho.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback i just submitted the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

So like I guessed, you don't need to listen to the message event of the client. You already have the message object via the initial command trigger.

```js
if (message.member.voice.channel) {
    const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    const dispatcher = connection.play('C:\Users\jayja\Downloads\Bruh Sound Effect 2.mp3 ');

    dispatcher.on('start', () => {
        console.log('audio.mp3 is now playing!');
    });

    dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('audio.mp3 has finished playing!');
    });

    // Always remember to handle errors appropriately!
    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
}
```

This should be all you need. You also might find [this guide](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/topics/voice.md) interesting to read.